# Sequence of linear continuous operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $Y$ be normed space, and $T_n:X\rightarrow Y, n\in \mathbb{N}$ is a sequence of linear continuous operators.

Prove that the following statements are equivalent.

(a) If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges, then $T_n (x_n)\rightarrow 0$.

(b) $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\Vert T_n \Vert \lt \infty$.

I have this.

***Proof (b) $\Rightarrow$ (a):***
$$T_n(x_n)\le \Vert T_n \Vert \Vert x_n \Vert,$$
but from (b): $ \Vert T_n \Vert<\infty$, 

and from (a): $x_n\rightarrow 0$, 
hence $T_n (x_n)\rightarrow 0$.

***Proof (a) $\Rightarrow$ (b):*** 
I'm stuck here. I thought: let $y_n=a_nx_n$, where $\Vert y_n \Vert=1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges. $T_n (y_n)=\Vert T_n\Vert \epsilon_n$, where $\epsilon_n$ are quite small. $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\Vert T_n \Vert=\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} T_n(y_n)=\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} T_n(x_n)a_n $, but $T_n (x_n)$ can converge to $0$ slowly, so I don't know how to pick up the right $a_n$.

I'm not sure how to proceed and maybe my approach is completely wrong. Could anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Proof of a) implies b). Suppose b) is false. We can find integers $n_k$ such that $n_1<n_2<...$ and $\|T_{n_k}\|>k^{2}$. There exists a vector $x_k$ of norm $1$ such that $\|T_{n_k}(x_k)\|>k^{2}$. Let $y_k=\frac {x_k} {k^{2}}$. Since $\sum \|y_k\|<\infty$, the series $\sum y_k$ is convergent (by completeness of $X$) but $Ty_k$ does not tend to $0$ so a) is false.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it has given an idea to me how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

For b implies a, note you are not just using that each $T_n$ has finite norm, but actually that their supremum is finite.  You should write it more carefully.

For a implies b, use the [uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle).  You might like to use the contrapositive: if b fails, there exists $x$ such that $\|T_n x\|$ is unbounded.  Try to use this to construct a sequence $x_n$ with $\sum x_n$ convergent but $T_n x_n \not\to 0$.  It may help to pass to some subsequences.

Comment: Uniform Boundedness Principle is not needed. You can prove a) implies b) just from definitions.